# Possible to dynamically join a related model in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Say there's a project that involves a lot of tables, all of which reference a single table that holds a field called `group ID`. However, not all of the tables reference this single table directly.

For example, the db contains a `garages` table, and each garage is referenced by rows in a `cars` table, and each car is referenced by rows in a `tire` table. I want to organize the data into two groups, `group1` and `group2`. Each garage has a `group ID`, however the cars and tires do not. Here is a diagram of the tables:
[image: Diagram of my example database]

As you can see, assets in group 1 are highlighted red, and assets in group 2 are highlighted yellow. But not all rows highlighted necessarily have a group ID. You can imagine how this may go even longer, with hub caps having forgien keys for their respective tires, bolts with forgien keys to their respective hub caps, etc.

Is there a way to dynamically call an EF query that can get the `group ID` from the related garage, given EITHER a child car, tire, hub cap, and so on? Implementation might be something like this:

```
var tire = Context.Tires.where(t => t.ID == 3).FirstOrDefault<Tire>();
tire.findShortestJoinToEntity(entity => entity.GetProperty("GroupID") != null);
// Returns 2, the group of "Toyota Tires"
```

In more technical terms, it would need to recursively check for any forgien keys in the passed in model, then all the forgein keys of the referenced models, all their referenced models, etc. until there are either no more forgein keys or a field with the passed in name is found.

Comment: Can you tell us which properties these classes contains, and the relationship between them? Or, you could try to draw a simple database Diagram, it can help us to know your requirement more clearly.

Comment: Why does this need to be dynamic? Linq expressions already do this for us but in a type safe way, what is the use case where you need the field name to be cast as a string?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for an SQL based solution?

Comment: It would need to be dynamic in the sense that it checks an unspecified number of entities. I don't necessarily need to pass in a string, just something to identify the field I am looking for. The project I'm actually working in will require SQL, and there are multiple tables with this GroupID. The goal is to find the query to the nearest table with a GroupID (aka least number of joins), then trace through the path to get there to find the correct `GroupID` for the specific item I'm calling it on.

Comment: This may be a case of sql normalization going too far.  Is this data readonly or do you need to make updates to it?  Are you able to create a timed process to pull this data into a single flat table for use in this project? If you can't do that, then consider a sql view.  Pulling from a single table will cause a lot less strain on the system than writing ef gymnastics.

Comment: @jGroot this level of normalisation is a good enough design, for modern ORM frameworks its no problem, the issue here is the automation, generally it is not a good idea to try for this level of automation or dynamic querying, you could do it, but there are usually difference approaches that would be far superior in the long run.

Comment: @CalebBertrand can you be more specific is your actual requirement? I think you would be better off finding a solution that meets you half way. For instance your example logic uses EF, but you mention SQL... You shouldn't try to be too abstract here, offer us an example that is more in-line with your real world requirement.

Comment: If you are trying to build a dynamic interface like Json2Table.com or a generic report generator or something like that then there are still different approaches that simplify this type of logic. If it is because GroupID is specifically a business key that you want to base generic business logic from then again, there are much better design solutions to assist with this type of querying, but the solution is easier if you are using an ORM like EF, or atleast vastly different if you ned to do it purely in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using reflection, it is not the ideal solution due to possible performance issues, but it does what you are looking for.

The key idea here is having all entity classes implementing a common interface `IEntity` so we can call a recursive method over any entity. Also assumes that we have both parentId (foreign key) and parent object in any entity, although you can tweak the method to use only the parentId, I have put the parent object only to take advantage of EF tracking mechanism linking parents and child entities

```cs
    public interface IEntity
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Group : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Garage : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual int GroupId { get; set; }
        public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    }

    public class Car : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual int GarageId { get; set; }
        public virtual Garage Garage { get; set; }
    }

    // ... other entity classes here


    public static class EntityExtensions
    {
        public static int FindGroupId(this IEntity entity, Context context, string propertyName = null)
        {
            var groupId = 0;

            if (entity != null)
            {
                var entityType = entity.GetType();

                if (entity is Group)
                {
                    // we found it
                    groupId = propertyName == null
                        ? entity.Id
                        : (int)entityType.GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(entity);
                }
                else
                {
                    // look into properties for parent entities
                    foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
                    {
                        if (property.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual
                            && property.PropertyType.GetInterface(nameof(IEntity)) != null)
                        {
                            // it is parent entity
                            var parentEntity = property.GetValue(entity) as IEntity;

                            if (parentEntity == null)
                            {
                                // if parent entity is null, let's get it from db
                                var parentIdName = $"{property.PropertyType.Name}Id";
                                var parentId = (int)entityType.GetProperty(parentIdName).GetValue(entity);
                                parentEntity = context.Find(property.PropertyType, parentId) as IEntity;
                            }

                            groupId = FindGroupId(parentEntity, context, propertyName);
                        }

                        if (groupId > 0)
                        {
                            // we found it
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return groupId;
        }
    }
```